# Use of expression "statistically significantly positive"

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, terminology

Suppose one estimates a linear model 
$$
y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\varepsilon
$$
and finds that $\hat\beta_1>0$ and the $p$-value associated with $\hat\beta_1$ is lower than the chosen significance level. Can one say that

> $\hat\beta$ is **statistically significantly positive**?

I am more used to the expression

> $\hat\beta$ is positive and statistically significant.

Is there a difference in the meanings of the two expressions? Can one use them interchangeably?

Comment: Piling on the adverbs is poor English, that's all.

Comment: Everyone will know what you mean. Did someone ask you to write it the first way instead of the second? The best way might be to report $\hat{\beta}$ with some margin of error and a confidence level e.g. "We found $\hat{\beta} = 3 \pm 1.44$ with 95% confidence." Maybe throw on the p-value, too, in case someone is more skeptical and wants to evaluate your work at $\alpha = 0.01$ or something.

Comment: @Dave, it is not me who is writing this. I am reading this and finding it a little unorthodox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is the same. If you say that $\hat \beta$ is statistically significant, that's a short way to say that it's significantly different from 0, and "different from 0" is not the same as "greater than 0", obviously.

If I read:

> $\hat \beta$ is statistically significantly positive

I understand that it has been tested for being greater than 0 (one tailed test), if I read instead:

> $\hat \beta$ is positive and statistically significant

I understand that it has been tested for being different from 0 (two tailed test), so in the end, even if the result is the same, the procedure seems to have been different.

Comment: A very interesting perspective. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is not a difference in meaning though the first one sounds strange to me. I would go with the second option or would word it as:

> $\beta_1$ is statistically significantly greater than zero.

because that is the most common wording I've personally seen.

Comment: The definition of *positive* is literally *greater than zero*. Therefore, your alternative must have the exact same meaning as *statistically significantly positive* and it uses 5 words instead of 3. I wonder if it is actually better. Perhaps  it is better in the sense of not piling on the adverbs (as per whuber's comment to the OP).

Comment: Yes it's wordier though I find it easier to read. But that may be because it's just more common and so I'm used to seeing it.

Comment: Thank you, Patrick.